# awk command of add column to std over repeated row

Tags: awk

i have a dataset as file:

```
1   aaa 1
1   aaa 3
1   aaa 5
1   ccc 9
1   ccc 2
1   ccc 2
1   ddd 4
1   ddd 6
1   ddd 8
1   ddd 1
2   ddd 5
2   ddd 12
2   ddd 13
```

i want to standard deviation of grouped data:

for examles
at

```
1   aaa
```

have 1,3,5 values.
std of these is 2,00

at

```
2   ddd
```

have 5,12,13 values.
std of these is ~ 4,36

i have tried,

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }
  NR==FNR{ 
    a[$1,$2]+=$3
    next
  }
  {delta = $3 - avg; avg += delta / NR; mean2 += delta * ($3 - avg); }
  { $(NF+1)=sqrt(mean2 / NR) }
  1
' file file
```

Desired output:

```
1   aaa 1   2,00
1   aaa 3   2,00
1   aaa 5   2,00
1   ccc 9   4,04
1   ccc 2   4,04
1   ccc 2   4,04
1   ddd 4   2,99
1   ddd 6   2,99
1   ddd 8   2,99
1   ddd 1   2,99
2   ddd 5   4,36
2   ddd 12  4,36
2   ddd 13  4,36
```

Comment: Are you asking for an algorithm to calculate standard deviation (if so you're in the wrong forum) or how to implement an algorithm you already know in awk (if so show the algorithm in your question) or something else?

Comment: tanks for your attention @EdMorton. Of course I didnt ask algorithm to calculate st. If you look at my trial, you can see my algorithm. i couldnt implement the algorithm to my code as i wanted.

Comment: Of course I see some code in your script implementing **an** algorithm but if it doesn't do what you want then the algorithm you programmed is obviously not the algorithm you want which led to my question about whether you needed help coming up with an algorithm or help implementing an algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems in your script are:

- You are confusing the *fixed* values (such as average) with the
  *accumulating* values (such as sum of delta**2) and calculating
  them changing the values line by line in the 2nd loop.
- You need to use each count of the dataset as the denominator, not `NR`.
  (To be specific, `count-1` to calculate the standard deviation *of sample*)

Implementing the formula of calculating standard deviation *of sample*,
would you please try:

```
awk '
  BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
  NR==FNR { 
    a[$1,$2] += $3
    n[$1,$2]++
    next
  }
  # the following block is executed just before processing 2nd "file"
  FNR==1 {
    for (i in a) {
      avg[i] = a[i] / n[i]
    }
  }
  # the following block is executed while reading the 2nd "file"
  { var[$1,$2] += ($3 - avg[$1,$2]) * ($3 - avg[$1, $2]) }
  END {
    for (i in a) {
      str = i; sub("\x1c", "\t", str)   # convert 2-D element separator to a tab
      print str, sqrt(var[i] / n[i] - 1)
    }
  }
' file file
```

Single loop version (more common):

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
  { 
    a[$1,$2] += $3              # sum of xi
    a2[$1,$2] += $3 * $3        # sum of xi * xi
    n[$1,$2]++
  }
  END {
    for (i in a) {
      avg[i] = a[i] / n[i]
      var[i] = (a2[i] - n[i] * avg[i] * avg[i]) / (n[i] - 1)
      if (var[i] < 0) var[i] = 0        # avoid rounding error
      str = i; sub("\x1c", "\t", str)   # convert 2-D element separator to a tab
      print str, sqrt(var[i])
    }
  }
' file
```

Output:

```
1   ddd 2.98608
1   aaa 2
2   ddd 4.3589
1   ccc 4.04145
```

**[EDIT]**
If you want to append the stdev.s values to the original data set side by side,
please try the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
  NR==FNR { 
    a[$1,$2] += $3              # sum of xi
    a2[$1,$2] += $3 * $3        # sum of xi * xi
    n[$1,$2]++
    next
  }
  # the following block is executed just before processing 2nd "file"
  FNR==1 {
    for (i in a) {
      avg[i] = a[i] / n[i]
      var[i] = (a2[i] - n[i] * avg[i] * avg[i]) / (n[i] - 1)
      if (var[i] < 0) var[i] = 0        # avoid rounding error
      str = i; sub("\x1c", "\t", str)   # convert 2-D element separator to a tab
      std[i] = sprintf("%.2f", sqrt(var[i]))
    }
  }
  # the following block is executed while reading the 2nd "file"
  { $(NF+1) = std[$1,$2] }
  1
' file file
```

Output:

```
1   aaa 1   2.00
1   aaa 3   2.00
1   aaa 5   2.00
1   ccc 9   4.04
1   ccc 2   4.04
1   ccc 2   4.04
1   ddd 4   2.99
1   ddd 6   2.99
1   ddd 8   2.99
1   ddd 1   2.99
2   ddd 5   4.36
2   ddd 12  4.36
2   ddd 13  4.36
```

Comment: thank you @tshiono . single loop version is as i want. is there any way to keep all input. is it possible to equal row count of input and output?

Comment: Thank you for the prompt feedback. I've updated my answer with the script to produce your desired output (although I had wanted to leave it as your homework :)

Comment: I want you to know I'm doing trials several. But I couldn't get out of it because I was new to awk. thank you so much again @tshiono